# CSS Specific Aside Positioning like Facebook

Tags: html, css

I am absolutely fascinated to how Facebook positioned their two asides and a section.

E.g.: Groups | Newsfeed | Ads, Pop-Ups, etc.

I have my HTML and CSS here. I am trying to centre my main section in the middle and put a sticky aside on the right.

It ain't really working my way.

HTML:

```
<?php
require_once 'misc/header.php';
require_once 'misc/footer.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page_wrap">
            <header id="title">
                <img src="images/Icon.png" id="titleIcon">Retnix
            </header>
            <div id="page-content">
                <div id="content-block">
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
                    typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
                    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown 
                    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a 
                    type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
                    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining 
                    essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with 
                    the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum 
                    passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
                    like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </div>
            </div>
            <aside>
                dsadas
            </aside>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{padding:0; margin: 0;}

@font-face
{
    font-family: 'infinityregular';
    src: url('../fonts/infinity-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/infinity-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Infinity.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

#page_wrap
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#page-content    
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

#content-block
{
    background-color: #ccccff;
    white-space: normal;
    font-family: 'infinityregular';;
    font-size: 24px;
}

header
{
    background-color: #66ff66; 
    padding: 10px;
}

#title
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: 'infinityregular';
}

#titleIcon
{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: -13px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

aside
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
    clear: left;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Kind Regards, and 
Thanks in Advance.
Alex.

Answer (score 0):

to #page-content add float:left; & from aside remove clear:left;